# Powershell - Filter an Excel File

Tags: excel, powershell

I would like to add a filter for an Excel file within a PowerShell script.

So "if you find in column D the entry "Listener", make the whole row invisible, so filter it out, so that only rows are shown where no "Listener" occurs.

Can I implement this with PowerShell somehow? I tried but it didn't work.

i tried it with this :

```
$column = 4 # column D
$filename = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Test.XLS"
$criteria = "Listener"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($filename)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$usedrange = $worksheet.UsedRange
$usedrange.EntireColumn.AutoFilter()
$usedrange.AutoFilter($column, $criteria)
$worksheet.UsedRange.offset($column,4).EntireLine.Delete()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$column = 4 # column D
$filename = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Test.XLS"
$criteria = "Listener"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$workbook  = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($filename)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.Activate()

# find the number of used rows in the table
$rowMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
# hide rows that match the criteria
# go from bottom to top
# if your file does not have column headers, use $row -gt 0
for ($row = $rowMax; $row -gt 1; $row--) {
    if ($worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $column).Value() -eq $criteria) {
        $worksheet.Rows($row).Hidden = $true
    }
}

# save and close the workbook
$workbook.Close($true)

# quit Excel and clean up the COM objects from memory
$Excel.Quit()
# IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

---

**Edit**

I may have misinterpreted your question and instead of hiding the rows that match the criteria like in the code above, all you need is to turn on an Autofilter on column 'D':

```
$column = 4 # column D
$filename = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Test.XLS"
$criteria = "Listener"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$workbook  = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($filename)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.Activate()

# find the number of used rows in the table
$rowMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
# add the autofilter to to column D
[void]$worksheet.Range("D$(1):D$($rowMax)").AutoFilter(1,"<>$criteria")

# save and close the workbook
$workbook.Close($true)

# quit Excel and clean up the COM objects from memory
$Excel.Quit()
# IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```